# Understanding transaction session with lazy loading in Spring JPA Hibernate

Tags: spring, exception, jpa, lazy-loading, spring-transactions

I would like to get some clarification regarding lazy loading and session boundaries etc.

My code structure is as follows

```
@Entity

class A {

....

  @OneToOne(fetch=LAZY)
  private B b;

  ..
}

@Entity
class B {

 private id;

 private name;    

}

@Transactional(SUPPORTS)
ADao {
  A findById(int id);  
}

@Transactional(SUPPORTS)
LayerDB {

    A getAForId(int i) {
      return adao.findById(i);
    }

}

//Note that there is no transactional attribute here
LayerB {

   public boolean doSomethingWithAandB(int aId) {
    A a = LayerDB.getAForId(aId);
    if(a.getB().getName().equals("HIGH"))
     return true;
    return false;
   }

}

//start transaction here
@Transaction(REQUIRED)
LayerC {

    LayerB layerb;

    private handleRequest(int id) {

       layerb.doSomethingWithAandB(id);

    }
}
```

Now when we try to access B in entity A within the method

```
doSomethingWithAandB
```

Am getting a lazy initialization exception when trying to access B.

Even though the method is within the transaction created in LayerC, still i get the following exception

```
Exception : org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

But on changing the following two methods as :

```
@Transactional(SUPPORTS)
LayerDB {

   A getAForId(int i) {
      A a = adao.findById(i);
      a.getB().getName();
      return a;
    }

}

//Note that there is no transactional attribute here
LayerB {

   public boolean doSomethingWithAandB(int aId) {
     A a = LayerDB.getAForId(aId);
     if(a.getB().getName().equals("HIGH"))
     return true;
    return false;
  }

}
```

Why is it not using the transaction / session created in LayerC ?

Even though we have SUPPORTS on the DBLayer, is it creating a separate 'session'.

Any pointers for proper understand would help me a great deal.

Thank you.

Comment: From what I tried,

Component A calls module X

module X calls Component B

where Component A and B are spring managed,

the transaction started by A cannot be used by component B because the cannot propagate through module X which is not spring managed.

Is this understanding right ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With lazy loading, when you request an object a of type A, you get an object a of type A. `a.getB()` however, will not be of type B, instead `a.getB()` is a proxy for B that can be resolved later on (that's the lazy loading part), but only in the persistence context in which a lives in.

Your second implementation does just that: it resolves B by calling `a.getB().getName()` while you are still in the `@Transaction`. Hibernate can now make a second request to the database to fetch B, and now `a.getB()` is really of type B and stays that way, so you can use it outside the persistence context.

Your first implementation skips that. A is fetched from the database, the `@Transactional` block ends, then you call `a.getB().getName()`, but now the persistence context is gone, `a.getB()` can not be fetched from the database, and an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thank you. Thats what I figured out. The proxy object for A and B are always there, but need to be fetched in only a spring managed component. 

But lets say two spring components are there X and Y, both have Transactional. Now lets say X calls Y to get only A with B configured to lazy load. Can I still do a.getB().getName() when control returns to X since X is also Transactional ?

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding. If a method is at-Transactional, the persistence context is established for all methods it calls, whether they are at-Transactional or not. The only exception is if the called method calls for a different transaction, for example if the caller is at-Transactional(Context1) and the callee is at-Transactional(Context2), or if the callee does transaction management on its own.

Comment: Sorry this answer is just wrong. LayerC setups the Transaction, thus there is a current open session and open transaction. Annotation @SUPPORTS reuses the current session and transaction. The lazy initialization would create a proxy object, but in this context the proxy object would still use the current session and transaction.

Answer (score 1):

What will happen if you add @Transactional(SUPPORTS) to LayerB ?
Propagation SUPPORT means that method joins the caller’s transaction.
By idea it will join the same transation LayerC created.
And since LayerDB's getAForId method runs within same transaction that means they have same persitance context there should not be problem with fetching B name.
I am just guessing.