# Hibernate Lazy Loading is not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, lazy-loading, eager-loading

```
// This is what I have in my Model Class...

    public class Quotation {
    @JoinColumn(name = "party_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Party party;
    }
```

And in my Controller I am loading the Quotation object like this:

```
// Load Quotation object by the Entity Manager:- em.find(Quotation.class, quoteId)

    quotation = quotationService.getQuoteHeadById(quoteId);
    log.debug( " party ID --> "+ quotation.getParty.getId() );
```

But I am not getting even the Party ID of the Party table/object in this Lazy Loading. But if I change the fetch type to Eager, then the log.debug() gives me the ID perfectly.

Am I wrong at anything???

Comment: try  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)

Comment: Can u provide query code?

Comment: @Eva Mariam: (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false) did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Udit Khare: em.find(Quotation.class, quoteId) is used for getting the object. em is the instance of EntityManager. 

Also tried, Query query = em.createQuery(" FROM Quotation q WHERE p.id = :quoteId "); 

Neither working.

Comment: @Backbencher I see that you using hibernate annotations on the field. Rather can you place the hibernate annotations on the getter methods and try. Make sure you move all hibernate annotations on to getter methods as we cannot have mix and match field and getter annotations.

Comment: @Backbencher did u get a chance to try the above comment?

Comment: @Sunnapu , I did not try Annotation on getter method yet. Rests did not work.

Comment: @Backbencher I have updated my answer below and provided more details. Hope that helps, unless I misinterpreted your question.

Answer (score 1):

> But I am not getting even the Party ID of the Party table/object in
>   this Lazy Loading.

Below is the behavior with  `@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`. Note that the behavior is different when we use hibernate annotations on field vs getters.

In your entity classes you are using `hibernate annotations on the field`. With this if you call even the getId() method as in `quotation.getParty.getId()` on the entity it results in initializing the proxy (of party object) and hits the database to fetch it. So the transaction has to be active if not it will result in throwing `lazyinitializationexception`.

If the intent is only to get the Id of the entity you can place the hibernate `annotations on the getter methods`. This doesn't initialize the proxy (of party object) to return the id and so doesn't need an active transaction. But accessing any other property other than id will need active transaction and will result in hitting the database.

Have a look at related bug at [HHH-3718](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3718)

So, in your party entity use property/getter AccessType instead of field access. As an example instead of

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(...)
private long id;
```

place them on the getters

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(...)
public long getId() { ... }
```

Make sure you make similar changes to the other fields of the `Party` entity. You can later explore another option of using `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY/FIELD)` instead to get the same effect.

Moving on to the `EAGER`

> But if I change the fetch type to Eager, then the log.debug() gives me
>   the ID perfectly.

This is because the `FetchType.EAGER` results in fetching the party entity eagerly (no proxy) up front and so we are able to get the id and other properties of party entity. Note that, this results in either a JOIN/extra SELECT query based on configuration.

> Am I wrong at anything???

I don't see anything wrong here and it is all because the field vs getter access type have different behavior. So if you are using filed level access, the Hibernate would initialize the proxy even for getting the id of an associated object as per the [bug HHH-3718](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3718) or until it gets resolved.

And a related topic on hibernate forum regarding field vs property access type that might be of interest [Field Vs Property access](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2349555)

Hope this answers your query.

Comment: Not sure why this has been down voted. Providing the reason would help update the answer or correct it accordingly.

Comment: I did not downvoted it, u know I dont have 15 reputation yet.Thank You very much for your clear picture. I will try it.

Comment: @Backbencher I got it. By the way, would be interested to see if my answer above helped you regarding why lazy loading is not working and how to make it work?

Comment: @Backbencher any luck with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

For getting LAZY fields, you need to be inside a transaction. Your controller method seems not transnational. Get an idea from: [Understanding transaction session with lazy loading in Spring JPA Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871503/understanding-transaction-session-with-lazy-loading-in-spring-jpa-hibernate)

Comment: I just have declared the method Transactional in ServiceImpl. Still having the same issue...... "could not initialize proxy - no Session".

The ServiceImpl is as below:

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public Quotation getQuoteHeadById( Long quoteId)  {
  return quotationDao.getQuoteHeadById(quoteId);
 }

Comment: well, then have to check your project configuration too. Transaction have to configure in application context properly. Do you have any github link?

Comment: No brother I don't have this project in github. But for reference, @Transaction on top of other required methods are working fine. Just having issue in this specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

Hibernate.initialize(quotation.getParty());

Answer (score 0):

First of all set transactional at service level. Then configure the hibernate properties like

```
<prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
```

I don't know your configuration, but I hope it will work.
(Note: Remember it may be unsafe)

Answer (score 0):

To get party object from quotation object, you have to use left join fetch on your query. Then you will be able to access your party object from quotation object .

Write a jpql query like this:

```
SELECT q from Quotation q left join fetch q.party p
```

Then you will not get "could not initialize proxy - no Session" error . 
By the way, it is a very common error. It means you are trying to access a object which you did not fetch by your query. 
Hope this answer help.

Comment: That didn't work. And that actually not the theme of Lazy loading I think. If I get the Quotation object, I must get the Party ID on lazy loading with hibernate entity manager